# How to create linux installation wizard CUI like this?

Tags: linux

[image: installation wizard CUI]

I make create a installation wizard GUI. Can you recommend some software to generate such dialogs?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. If you're looking for software, please consult [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185).

Comment: @Izzy I edited the question to ask to recommend some software. Is it on-topic now?

Comment: Could be `ncurses` as well as `dialog`

Comment: @Mawg On-Topic yes, but still in the "unclear" section (which is why I didn't make that edit). Does OP want a C++ library to integrate the menu into some software? Or shall it rather be used via shell scripting (so dialog/whiptail would apply)? What features are needed: just simple menus, or also inputs, checkboxes, fancy progress bars, file-pickers…? "Like this {screenshot}" is absolutely insufficient (and technically speaking, it's not even a GUI, is it? Rather a "text-based UI" – but allright, let's not split hairs).